# WGET on Windows through PHP exec() doesn't work

Tags: php, windows, exec, wget

I can't get `wget` to work when called from PHP through `exec()`.

The code is:

`exec('wget -b --timeout=300 --no-check-certificate -O c:\wgetlog.txt http://localhost/project/someparam/somevalue > c:\wgetout.txt')`

The called URL is an action from a project based on Zend Framework that manipulates some data in a MySQL database.

When the above is executed, only "c:\wgetout.txt" is created, and is empty.

The setup is as follows:

- Windows 7
- XAMPP
- PHP ver 5.3.5
- wget latest version from [here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm)
- PHP `safe_mode` is Off

wget is installed in "C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin", and this is added to the Windows PATH variable.

I know the wget setup is working because when running the above exec parameter (as echoed)

`wget -b --timeout=300 --no-check-certificate -O c:\\wgetlog.txt http://localhost/project/someparam/somevalue > c:\\wgetout.txt`

in a command prompt, it runs fine, I get the expected results in the database, and both files "C:\wgetlog.txt" and "C:\wgetout.txt" are created, with the latter containing wget's output (process id, etc).

**LATER EDIT:**

Got it working thanks to Crontab's suggestion and used the absolute path for calling `wget`, also enclosed it in double quotes.

Used WSH COM object to run it instead of plain `exec()`.

Also, on Windows, the `-b` parameter doesn't work if the output isn't directed somewhere. As I'm not particularly interested in the output, I directed it to `> NUL 2>&1` (this includes errors also).

I quickly made this function to help me test my project on a Windows machine and have `wget` working, so here it is, in case anyone finds it useful:

```
public function execWget($URL, $intTimeout = 30, $blnInBackground = true) {
    if (preg_match("/Win/i", PHP_OS)) {
        $runCommand = '"C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\wget" ' . ($blnInBackground?'-b ':'') . '--timeout=' . (int)$intTimeout . ' --no-check-certificate ' . $URL . ($blnInBackground?' > NUL 2>&1':'');
        $WshShell = new COM("WScript.Shell");
        $oExec = $WshShell->Run($runCommand, 7, false);
    } else {
        $runCommand = 'wget ' . ($blnInBackground?'-b ':'') . '--timeout=' . (int)$intTimeout . ' --no-check-certificate ' . ($blnInBackground?'-O /dev/null ':'') . $URL . ($blnInBackground?' > /dev/null 2>&1':'');
        exec($runCommand);
    }
}
```

Please mind that it's customized for my own setup (absolute path to `wget`), it's for testing purposes only (only use the Windows machine for testing, the actual production machine runs Linux), the OS checking method might not be the best, etc.

Comment: Is `wget` in your script's path?  Chances are your script isn't running with the same path you are when you pull up a command prompt.  Try using an absolute path to call `wget`.

Comment: why are you using wget? there is curl (http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) or fsocket_open (http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php) for that

Comment: @machineaddict it's what I have at hand right now, don't have curl installed on this win machine

Comment: @Crontab I used the absolute path and worked. But, I have 2 problems: 1. The script waits for wget to finish 2. Not a problem, more of a questionmark: what settings do I have to make so I don't have to use the full path to `wget` in the script ?

Comment: @Crontab Thanks for the help! If you'll post your comment as an answer, I'll be glad to accept it.

Comment: @talereader If you have XAMPP installed, you just need to activate curl from php.ini

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using an absolute path to `wget` - it's probably not in your script's path.  To avoid using the absolute path, you could try adding `putenv("PATH=<whatever-paths-you-need-colon-delimited>");` in your script before you access `wget`.  Another way would be to directly modify the PATH environment variable of whatever user is running your webserver (and hence whichever user runs the PHP interpreter).